# monodroid application fails to update ui in release mode

Tags: xamarin.android

Our Monodroid application functions well enough in debug mode - the UI is responsive. The problem is that in release mode more often than not the UI is not updated as expected - meaning we have to leave and return to the application so see the change rendered.
Of course all changes are performed in the UI thread.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you updating the UI? Can you show some code?

---

One frequent cause of problems when changing debug->release is that the Mono Linker may remove properties needed for reflection.

To stop this happening, you can change the Linker settings, or you can include additional code which tricks the Linker into not removing the methods you need.

For more info on this, see http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking

An example of a file that tricks the linker is [LinkerIncludePlease.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20BestSellers/BestSellers/BestSellers.Droid/LinkerIncludePlease.cs)

Comment: The Xamarin docs pointed me the right way. It was the linking issue.